# How can we get wheel joint2D anchor values using code inside unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can we access wheel joint2D's anchor values and suspension values using c# code

I tried several methods to get the values. but I count get any result. can anyone give any hint or suggestion, how to do this?

Let's say in start method I need anchor x value=2 and y value=3 and the suspension value also some value. but this values should be changed via script, not in the inspector
[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelJoint2D.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelJoint2D.html
Without more information regarding your issue, this is as much as users could provide you with.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a reference to the wheel joint then set the connected anchor and suspension values like this.

```
public WheelJoint2D wheel;
public Vector2 someVector2;
public float dampingRatio;
public float bar;
public float fooBar;

void Update()
{
    wheel.connectedAnchor = someVector2;
    wheel.suspension.dampingRatio = foo;
    wheel.suspension.frequency = bar;
    wheel.suspension.angle = fooBar;

}
```

In this example, you would have to drag in the reference to the `WheelJoint2D` in the inspector, but there are other ways to do this through code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
I change the code a bit, by referencing your code. here it is

```
public GameObject wheelObject;
private WheelJoint2D wheel;
public Vector2 someVector2;
public float breakeForce=10;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    wheel = wheelObject.GetComponent<WheelJoint2D>();
    wheel.anchor = someVector2;
    wheel.breakForce = breakeForce;

}
```